# SVG content disappearing from IFrame documentContent

Tags: javascript, plotly-dash

I'm attempting to replicate the content in a particular IFrame element inside of a modal to avoid unnecessary DB calls. I am invoking a clientside callback via Python (see [here](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks)) that returns the index of a particular IFrame element I would like to replicate in my modal.

Here is the snippet of Python code that toggles my modal and tracks the index of the most recently clicked figure to replicate:

```
@app.callback(
    [Output('my-modal', 'is_open'),
    Output('modal-clone', 'children')],
    [Input(f'button{k}', 'n_clicks_timestamp') for k in range(20)] + 
    [State('my-modal', 'is_open')])
def toggle_modal(*data):

    clicks, is_open = data[:20], data[20]

    modal_display = not is_open if any(clicks) else is_open

    clicked = clicks.index(max(clicks))

    return [modal_display, clicked]

app.clientside_callback(
    ClientsideFunction(namespace='clientside', function_name='clone_figure'),
    Output('modal-test', 'children'),
    [Input('modal-clone', 'children'), Input('modal-figure', 'id')]
)
```

And the following Javascript:

```
window.dash_clientside = Object.assign({}, window.dash_clientside, {

    clientside: {

        clone_figure: function(clone_from, clone_to) {

            source = document.getElementById(clone_from);

            console.log(document.getElementById(clone_to))
            console.log(document.getElementById(clone_to).contentDocument);

            clone = document.getElementById(clone_to);

            // set attributes of clone here using attributes from source

            return null

        }

    }

});
```

Now, from my `console.log()` statements, I noticed the following (note that `modal-clone` in the screenshot corresponds to `modal-figure` in my example):

[image]

How is `contentDocument` changing between these two log statements? Any insight would be greatly appreciated, I am stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you need to `addEventListener()` to the IFrame element:

```
clone_spray: function(clone_from, clone_to) {

    source = document.getElementById(clone_from);
    clone = document.getElementById(clone_to);

    if (!clone) {return null;}

    clone.addEventListener("load", function() {

        // set attributes of clone here using attributes from source
```